# Как лучше всего обработать ответ?

Tags: android

Как лучше всего получить необходимые данные?

Есть:

```
byte[] data = null;
ByteArrayOutputSream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
baos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
data = baos.toByteArray();

String resultString = new String(data, "UTF-8");
System.out.println("--- data: " + resultString);
```

Выводим:

> System.out: --- data: {"hash":"a47754gfxhjh","photo":"fdgyfvhfdvbhfdssfbbv"}

Вопрос: как проще всего получить значения полученных полей "hash" и "photo" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это строка [в формате json](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)   - есть много библиотек, которые умеют парсить такой текст.

Моя самая любимая это [Google GSON](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/library/gson.php)

Comment: Я неправильно задал вопрос: тут, скорее, надо было спросить: как преобразовать String в JSON и из последнего получить данные. Сделал так: JSONObject json = new JSONObject (resultString); и получаем значения так: json.getString("photo");

Comment: JSON это всегда String...